# Variable offset and matching in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Good day, I would like to achieve something with a data frame, and I think it’s a combination of doing a variable offset and matching,  but I am not quite sure how to do it in R.

Sample data to replicate the original and desired output:

```
original = data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2), 
  Type = c("Live", "Live", "Live", "Live", "Live", "Dead"), 
  Number = c(100, 20, 30, 40, 50, NA))

desired = data.frame(
  ID = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2), 
  Type = c("Live", "Live", "Live", "Live", "Live", "Dead"), 
  Number = c(100, 20, 30, 40, 50, NA), 
  Number2 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 50))
```

Essentially what I would like to achieve is that when Type = “Dead”, then I want to get the last Number in the series when that ID was “Live.” It’s possible that the same ID can be live across a number of rows (e.g. ID = 2), but when an ID has Type = “Dead”, then I want to extract the last number at which it was live. The challenge is that it’s not the case that the preceding row always has the same ID so there needs to be some sort of search that I would like to generalise for all IDs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way

```
library(dplyr)
original %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(
    Number2 = if_else(Type=="Dead", last(Number[Type=="Live"]), NA_real_))
```

Here we group_by the ID then for each of the "Dead" values, find the last value of Number where the Type is Live, returning NA if not "Dead"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R option

```
(u <- Reduce(
  rbind,
  lapply(
    split(original, original$ID),
    function(v) {
      within(v, Number2 <- ifelse(Type == "Dead",
        tail(Number[Type == "Live"], 1), NA
      ))
    }
  )
))[order(as.numeric(row.names(u))), ]
```

which gives

```
  ID Type Number Number2
1  1 Live    100      NA
2  2 Live     20      NA
3  3 Live     30      NA
4  2 Live     40      NA
5  2 Live     50      NA
6  2 Dead     NA      50
```